# Symbology of elements with attachments AGOL

Tags: arcgis-online

In an ArcGIS Online web map, there is the possibility to highlight in some way the elements that do not have attachments.
The idea is that when you edit the element with Field Maps and add an image the symbology changes to another type.
How can I do it?